# Choose either excerpt or the_content

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set either the excerpt or the full content on my posts.
I'm using post format, so far everything works, but when I click on a specific post, only the excerpt is displayed in the full post (because only the excerpt is set on format-video, for ex.).

I would like my post formats to display the excerpt when it's on loop.php (home page), and the full content when it's on single.php
I am bad at php, but here is my code (which is obviously not working for a reason)

```
<?php if ( is_loop() ) { ?>
        <?php custom_excerpt('custom_index'); ?>    
    <?php } elseif ( is_single() ) : { ?>   
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Could anyone tell me where is the mistake in my code ? Or is there a better solution to perform what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: `is_loop()` should be `is_home()`. Also, you are mixing syntax here, only use curlies to enclose your statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<?php 
      if ( is_single() )
              the_content();
      else
              custom_excerpt('custom_index'); 
    ?>
```

in your post loop.It prints content if the post is single.php page otherwise custom_excerpt() data.

Comment: That's indeed the easiest way, I complicated my code too much for nothing. Thank you